# How do you delete a row using PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have been looking on how to delete a row in pytorch(torchtext.data.dataset.TabularDataset) but I'm not able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/text/blob/master/torchtext/data/dataset.py) for TabularDataset, it looks like the rows are stored in a field called `examples` which is a list.

So simply delete an element from examples

```
del dataset.examples[i]
```

Where `i` is the row index that you wish to delete.